# ValueError: multiclass format is not supported on ROC_Curve for text classification

Tags: svm, text-classification, roc, multiclass-classification, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to use ROC for evaluating my emotion text classifier model

This is my code for the ROC :

```
# ROC-AUC Curve
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_test_hat2)
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=1, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc)
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('ROC CURVE')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

This is the Error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-ef4ee0eff994> in <module>()
      2 from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 4 fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_test_hat2)
      5 roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
      6 plt.figure()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py in roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight, drop_intermediate)
    961     """
    962     fps, tps, thresholds = _binary_clf_curve(
--> 963         y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight
    964     )
    965 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py in _binary_clf_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight)
    729     y_type = type_of_target(y_true)
    730     if not (y_type == "binary" or (y_type == "multiclass" and pos_label is not None)):
--> 731         raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
    732 
    733     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_score, sample_weight)

ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

This is the y_test and y_test_hat2 :

```
y_test = data_test["label"]


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(data_test['tweet'])
classifier_linear2 = LinearSVC(verbose=1)
y_test_hat2=classifier_linear2.predict(test_vectors)
```

Shape of test_vectors = (1096, 11330)

Shape of y_test       = (1096,)

Label in y_test       = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ROC curve is based on *soft predictions*, i.e. it uses the predicted **probability** of an instance to belong to the positive class rather than the predicted **class**. For example with sklearn one can obtain the probabilities with `predict_proba` instead of `predict` (for the classifiers which provide it, [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba)).

Note: OP used the tag multiclass-classification, but it's important to note that ROC curves can only be applied to *binary* classification problems.

One can find a short explanation of ROC curves [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/87363/64377).